# isinstance function in if statement python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

As part of a lcm program I'm creating, I want a condition to determine whether the result of an expression is `integer` or `float`. After looking online, I found the `isinstance` function, which outputs a `boolean`. I want to be able to use that in the statement, and execute the respective . How exactly do I code it? This is an example:

```
num=input("Enter a number: ")
if isinstance(num,int):
  print("Float")
else:
  print("Integer")
```

Comment: Input is a string, you need to convert  it.

Comment: `input` will *always return a `str`*. What, exactly, are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go deeper =)

```
def int_of_float( n ) :
    try :
        num = int(num)
        return 'Integer'
    except ValueError :
        pass

    try :
        num = float(num)
        return 'Float'
    except ValueError :
        pass

    return 'Unknown'

num = input( 'need a number: ' )
print int_or_float( num )
```